# DataTable with a dropdown Column at the end

Tags: c#, windows, forms, windows-forms-designer

I already have a DataTable (dt). Now I would like to have a column at the end of the table in which I can select different numbers using the drop-down menu. I just can't find a function with which I can do that.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();// neuer DataTable dt wird erzeugt

foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
{                                   
  dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
}
if (dt.Columns.Count > 5) //prüfen ob Datum Kürzel und OK schon vorhanden sind 
{
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CODE", typeof(string))); 
  // here i want to add the DropDown Menu Column
  //Code is "ONE" or "TWO"
}
else //falss nicht --> hinzufügen
{
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OK", typeof(bool)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Datum", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Kürzel", typeof(string)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a numeric field (int) or string, whatever fits better to your data. It's not the problem of the data table itself how it is displayed later. You can display the table e.g. with a DataGridView, there you can select the column type as a column with combo boxes.